# How can we migrate questions to other SE sites?

Tags: support, migration

This question https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/15181/3192 does not belong here, and could be migrated to StackOverflow or Programmers.SE. (I am not implying that the question is good enough to be asked there.) However, when I flag the question and suggest migrating it, the only option I find is the migrate it to this meta site. Is this because I do not have sufficient reputation, or this is how the site is designed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of potential migration destinations is [intentionally limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96345/167443), and is [controlled by the development team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited/79961?noredirect=1#comment643718_79961).

If you think another site would be appropriate, flag using the "other" reason and explain. Moderators have the ability to migrate anywhere (doesn't mean it *will* get migrated, but we will look into it).

Comment: Thanks, did that!

Comment: You can also comment (perhaps as part of an "off topic/other" close vote) suggesting the OP ask on another (specific) site.  I've been told that customizing the migration list isn't available for beta sites, though graduated sites can add a small number of options.

Comment: I recommend against suggesting asking on another site until the migration has been decided (to prevent duplicate posts at the destination).

Comment: @Monica I've added a bit about customizing the list (didn't know all the details yet when I wrote the answer)

Answer (score 8):

## Don't Migrate Crap

This is Rule #1 of Migrations [as stated by Jeff Atwood Himself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89169/please-just-close-garbage-questions-instead-of-moving-them-to-programmers-se/89171#89171). This question is horrid, and should not be migrated as it is not appropriate for any site in the network.

If the question is not crap, then feel free to flag as [stated by Jim](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2113/7945).

Comment: Yeah, but that was not my point. This question is undoubtedly garbage on any SE site. However, I was more curious why there was only one option to migrate to, and since it was this question which got me thinking, I thought I might as well put it there as a "courtesy". :P

Comment: No problem @Happy! Just wanted to make sure that anyone else who stumbled upon this knows the first rule.