# Voting to transfer questions

Tags: support

Looking at this question from earlier: [How to avoid a player co-worker](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113817/how-to-avoid-a-player-co-worker), it looks like this would have been perfect for the Interpersonal Skills SE. However, it was closed for the "Questions require a goal" reason.

Under the off-topic sub-reasons when voting to close, there is a "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" option. However, this option only allows us to transfer the question here into Meta.

Is there a way to vote to be able to transfer questions to other SE sites? Do moderators even have that capability?

Overall, is there a better way to handle this without forcing the OP to manually go to another SE site to ask his question?

Comment: If I could have voted to close and selected that it belongs on another site (*and the specific site*) I would have.

Comment: I also suggest that you create a separate post if you plan to ask for a feature request, as this doesn't read like one (it's more support or discussion)... do you want new targets for migration? if that is true then it could be the basis for a request

Comment: I removed the feature request tag on this question, but yes, I can craft a separate request for that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to vote to be able to transfer questions to other SE sites? Do moderators even have that capability?

Yes there is, and yes mods have that power. Take a look at this post: [How can we migrate questions to other SE sites?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2112/73791)

Basically, as the targets are limited, the way to go is to **flag as "other"** and include there the reason for flagging and the possible target you suggest. For example, a sample phrasing for this situation could be:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Navigating the Workplace, and would better fit [Interpersonal SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com).

Given the post were not [trash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89171/332286) then one of our esteemed Mods will eventually come by and take the action they seems according to this situation.

> Overall, is there a better way to handle this without forcing the OP to manually go to another SE site to ask his question?

This is a bit harder, given the target sites are limited.

Indirectly, we could prevent this situations if users took more time to read what is off-topic here, or if they previously knew IPS... as we can see, it is something hard to achieve. IMHO, it is not rare that sometimes posts placed here could better fit IPS, and thus adding it as target could help.

Although I recall there is some guideline that Beta sites should not be target for Migration Qs if possible, to allow them to organically generate their own question flow... perhaps that is the reason why we don't have IPS as target.

Comment: I see. Not going to lie, from a systems perspective this seems silly and counter-intuitive. Despite what the comments said, the system sends the message to the OP needs to manually transfer, at least until a mod steps in to resolve the issue. On top of that, flagging "other" instead of choosing other options seems to be something that we (the voting users) have to know, and not something that is very intuitive.

Comment: But those concerns seem more appropriate for SE Meta, and not Workplace Meta, I suppose.

Comment: @panoptical yeah, it's not that intuitive, and also not swift enough so posts don't get DV-ted to hell and make it almost impossible to make a comeback. Our mods have to manually do the migration, create accounts for the people that commented/answered, etc, etc... not a straightforward task, but SE ways are not always 100% clear. Yes, you could try raising it on Meta SE, but I first suggest you pitch the idea here on a separate post regarding the target sites, and also join us on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) to chew it a bit so you get better reception

Comment: @panoptical StackExchange software and policies are not exactly the gold standard of intuitive. :)

Answer (score 2):

The author [asked that question on IPS already](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/15417/106), so there'd be no point in migrating it.

Moderators can migrate questions anywhere, but we're expected to do some basic diligence.  Migration can be confusing for new users -- wait, where'd my question go, and ok I followed a link but I don't seem to have an account here so can't comment, and... huh?  I'd rather see an author re-ask the question, which often needs some edits to fit on the other site anyway.  Sure, I'm willing to migrate to help out, but I try to ask myself if I'm helping the user by doing so.  (Sometimes yes, sometimes no, often a gut feeling.)

Also of interest: [related discussion on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/162102).

Answer (score 2):

Users get the privilege to close questions because it is assumed they know what kind of questions are acceptable *on that site*<sup>1</sup>. This assumption cannot be stretched to allow migration, because that requires the user to know what kind of questions are acceptable on the *target site*.

We should not migrate questions because they seem off-topic here, we should only migrate them when we are *sure* they would be on-topic on the target site.

Allowing users to migrate questions elsewhere could cause more problems than it solves. Even if this were allowed, we should have a "migrate privilege" decoupled from the close privilege.

Another way of looking at this is the "migrate privilege" is currently available only to the moderators. As Monica says, moderators have to do some basic diligence before migrating. Extending the "migrate privilege" to non-moderators would mean those users too would have to do that diligence.

The powers-that-be at SE decided not to extend the "migrate privilege" to non-moderators, and this was a reasonable decision due to following rules of migration:

- [Don't. Migrate. Crap.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/202356)
- [When in doubt, don't migrate.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32474/202356)

---

<sup>1</sup> This assumption is not entirely accurate, especially on "subjective" sites (such as The Workplace), as seen from the close/reopen <s>bickering</s> ping-pong that frequently happens here. :-)