# Add Interpersonal Skills SE as a migration target

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Following up from [this meta question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5290/voting-to-transfer-questions),

In the past few days, I've seen the following questions:

- [How to decline politely](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113913/how-to-decline-politely)
- [How to go around a colleague who keeps inviting me for religious activities?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113821/how-to-go-around-a-colleague-who-keeps-inviting-me-for-religious-activities)
- [How to avoid a player co-worker](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113817/how-to-avoid-a-player-co-worker)
- [Does mockery in the workplace help with employee bonding](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113776/does-mockery-in-the-workplace-help-with-employee-bonding)
- [Situational help needed - Teasing colleagues](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113775/situational-help-needed-teasing-colleagues)
- [Distracted by loud music](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113723/distracted-by-loud-music)
- [Radio in the break room. Good or bad?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113448/radio-in-the-break-room-good-or-bad)
- [Proven innocent of sexual harassment, but do not feel treated as such](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113319/proven-innocent-of-sexual-harassment-but-do-not-feel-treated-as-such)

Some of these have been closed, others have been answered, and answered well. However, it looks like these would be candidates for migration to the Interpersonal Skills SE, as these questions are more about dealing with people (albeit inside the office) and less about dealing with companies or workplaces.

Now, I have heard some discussion that it's not recommended by SE to transfer questions to a beta site, but it just seems that having the option to be able to transfer out these questions via a vote would be beneficial (as opposed to having to flag for a moderator), and I'd like to be able to discuss that here.

Right now, the only migration target that we can currently vote for is this meta, and not any other SE site. I would like to propose that we add IPS as a migration target.

Comment: Recommended reading: [When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79960/332286)

Comment: Even if we could add more migration options (which I'm pretty sure has been discussed and declined in the past), I know for certain that Beta sites are not to be included in migration lists.

Answer (score 9):

We've had [this discussion](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/lets-talk-academic-questions) about Academia in the past.  It's a bad idea.  If it's workplace related, it's workplace related.

Now, specifically towards IPS

1. IPS is, and remains in Beta for a reason.
2. The scope of what is appropriate for the workplace is more narrow than what may be appropriate for IPS
3. A course of action that is appropriate may be very different from a **professional**  standpoint than an interpersonal one
4. There may be workplace related issues that extend past the interpersonal.

With regards to #4:

[How to decline politely](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113913/how-to-decline-politely) specifically had issues that extended past the interpersonal as the querent was asked about how to decline an offer.  IF it had ended there, then this would indeed be an interpersonal issue.  However, since there was the potential for a loss of good press for the company, it was clearly a workplace issue.

[How to go around a colleague who keeps inviting me for religious activities?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113821/how-to-go-around-a-colleague-who-keeps-inviting-me-for-religious-activities) also was workplace related, as the issue was not just an interpersonal one, but also had HR related issues as to whether it could constitute workplace harassment and other HR issues

[How to avoid a player co-worker](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113817/how-to-avoid-a-player-co-worker) was simply off topic as there was no clearly addressable goal, merely looking for a term, possibly an HR issue, but still workplace related

The same applies to the rest of the examples.

A question can simply be a bad question and just because it's out of scope of this site does not mean that it is on topic for another.