# What is the proper way to get a question migrated to another board?

Tags: discussion, migration

I occasionally flag questions that, in my opinion, should be moved to a more appropriate board, such as Law.SE.  This seems to have no effect.

Is there a better way to get questions migrated to a different SE board?

Or...is that just not done anymore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we migrate questions to other SE sites?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/how-can-we-migrate-questions-to-other-se-sites)

Comment: So after reading that, I'm going to go with: That's just not done anymore.

Comment: No, that's not what it said. If you think a question should be migrated, use the custom moderator flag and explain why you think it should be migrated. There's an option to flag a question for migration, but the only site you can choose is Workplace Meta. But the number one rule is, if it's a bad question on any site, even if it might fit another site better, don't migrate it.

Comment: FWIW, It's also not-so-encouraged to migrate question from a "Mature" site to a Beta one, as to avoid injecting post to a Site in development and let it get to their user base and topic definition on their own... migration between "mature" sites is OK as long as what David mentioned holds and the question is not trash.

Comment: Apart from the "don't migrate crap" discussed below, keep in mind that few if any of our legal questions would be on-topic on [law.se]. Check their on-topic rules because you might be surprised that they [don't cover legal advice in specific situations](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice) (just like we don't).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can raise a custom flag for this so that we can look into the request.  Be aware though that [we don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89169/please-just-close-garbage-questions-instead-of-moving-them-to-programmers-se/89171#89171) - moving unsuitable questions to another site annoys the users (and moderators) on the other site and the question gets closed, rejected, or deleted - none of which helps the OP.

It's ok to leave a comment on the question indicating that the OP should post this question on another site (and provide a link) after searching and reading the tour there.  This prompts the user to re-evaluate their question and hopefully word it in a more site-suitable fashion, or to search and find the answer.

Or, it might be possible to edit the question so that it's more Workplace orientated, but do so in a way that doesn't change the intent.

Comment: "Don't migrate crap" is an important rule: I cannot recall the last time I actually migrated a question based on a simple flag. For migration to be successful you typically need a high-quality question with an OP that's actively participating in the effort to improve/reopen/migrate the question. At a rough estimate from my experience I would say less than 5% of all migration flags are accepted.